# IF condition with OR value

Tags: java, objective-c

I would like to know if is possibile re-write an `if` like this

```
int var = 0;
if ( var == 1 || var == 2 )
{
   //...
}
```

in somethings like this

```
int var = 0;
if ( var == (1 || 2) )
{
   //...
}
```

or similar. Thanks

Comment: you can have condition operators only on boolean values

Comment: in C condition like ( 1 || 2 ) always true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.23)

> Each operand of the conditional-or operator must be of type boolean or Boolean, or a compile-time error occurs.

so no, there is no better (and faster) way to code your condition.
(The same rules apply to the conditional-and operator)

Answer (score 3):

|| stands for or operator so it needs a condition on both of its sides so this is incorrect
as you are putting integer on both the sides of the || operator

Answer (score 1):

There is no such syntax with `if` in java.

If you have a large set of values in the `if` condition, you may use `switch` instead:

```
int var = ...;
switch(var) {
    case 1:
    case 2:
       // ...
       break;
    default:
       //else case
       break;
}
```

Edit:

With Java 8, you can also write:

```
int var = ...;
if (IntStream.of(1, 2, 3, 4).anyMatch(i -> var == i)) {
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible in Java. What you're asking is something similar to  sql `IN` operator.

`if(var == (1 || 2))` could easily be translated to `if(var IN [1,2])`, but Java doesn't suport that either.

As close you can get to is to use a collection :

`if(Arrays.asList(1,2).contains(var)){`

or a String

`if("1_OR_2".contains(String.valueOf(var))`

One other approach could be to build a function like

```
public static final boolean in(final int var, final int... vals) {
    for (int val : vals) {
        if (var == val) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And then, you'll call : `if(in(var,1,2)){` .

Or you could build a wrapper for `Integer`, and add `in` method there, so the method call may sound more natural( `if value x in [val1,val2 ... valN]`)

```
public final class Int {
    private final Integer val;

    public Int(final int val) {// avoid passing nulls
        this.val = val;
    }


    public boolean in(final int... vals) {
        for (int val : vals) {
            if (this.val.equals(val)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Int(1).in(1, 2, 3));
    }
}
```

Comment: `Arrays.asList(new int[]{1,2})` will return a `List<int[]>`. You must write `Arrays.asList(1,2)` to get a `List<Integer>`.